# error while inserting a node at end of a linked list

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, singly-linked-list, insertion

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data) {
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        SinglyLinkedListNode* tmp=new SinglyLinkedListNode();
        tmp->data=data;
        tmp->next=NULL;
        head=tmp;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        insertNodeAtTail(head->next,data);
    }
}
```

these are the errors which the compiler is giving after compilation.

```
solution.cc: In function ‘SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode*, int)’:
solution.cc:60:60: error: no matching function for call to ‘SinglyLinkedListNode::SinglyLinkedListNode()’
         SinglyLinkedListNode* tmp=new SinglyLinkedListNode();
                                                            ^
solution.cc:10:9: note: candidate: SinglyLinkedListNode::SinglyLinkedListNode(int)
         SinglyLinkedListNode(int node_data) {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
solution.cc:10:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
solution.cc:5:7: note: candidate: constexpr SinglyLinkedListNode::SinglyLinkedListNode(const SinglyLinkedListNode&)
 class SinglyLinkedListNode {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
solution.cc:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
solution.cc:5:7: note: candidate: constexpr SinglyLinkedListNode::SinglyLinkedListNode(SinglyLinkedListNode&&)
solution.cc:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
solution.cc:72:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
```

Comment: your SinglyLinkedListNode constructor has a parameter.

Comment: tail->next = tmp;
   tail = tail->next;  in the place of these two lines ,can we directly write tail=tmp; ??tmp and tail both are nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a default constructor for `SinglyLinkedList`, but you have a constructor that takes an `int`. You are also not returning anything from your `else` block.

You should also prefer to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` for pointer comparison.

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data) {
    if(head==nullptr) //Use nullptr
    {
        SinglyLinkedListNode* tmp=new SinglyLinkedListNode(data); //Construct with data
        tmp->data=data; //This line can probably be removed now?
        tmp->next=NULL;
        head=tmp;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        return insertNodeAtTail(head->next,data); //Make sure to return here aswell
    }
}
```